# Resources for Abelian surfaces

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I have recently gone through Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves and was looking for sources on Abelian surfaces but am struggling to find anything. I wasn't expecting to find the Arithmetic of Abelian surfaces but I can't find anyone's lecture notes or anything other than a book on moduli spaces. I am aware that there are plenty of resources for abelian varieties but I was wondering why there aren't anything for the dimension 2 case.

Comment: What distinguishes elliptic curves from general abelian varieties is that they can be described by Weierstrass equations and that they are naturally principally polarised. As soon as the dimension is $>1$ this fails so the theory of abelian surfaces is to a large extent the theory of all abelian varieties.

Comment: Would this be covered in Mumford?

Comment: I would suggest Mumford as the first port of call, yes.